# Viewing LaTeX Output in Emacs

Tags: macos, pdf, emacs, terminal, latex

I am trying to view the output of a LaTeX file in Emacs. I am following this guide:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-doc-view-with-auto-revert-to-view-latex-pdf-output-in-emacs/

I have done everything they said, but when I run `C-c C-c` and open the pdf in the other Emacs window, I get nonsense. Preferably, I want the pdf to immediately show in the other window when I run `C-c C-c`--I do a lot of live texing, and I need to periodically view the output.

Please note that I am running Emacs from the Mavericks command terminal. I have tried every suggest I could find on google and Stack Exchange, but nothing helps. At the moment I have configured my .emacs file as such:

```
(require 'xpdf)

(require 'ghostscript)

(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

However, this still does nothing. I am new to Emacs, so any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I have also tried `M-x doc-view-mode`, but it said "no match". Why doesn't doc-view mode work for me?

Comment: `doc-view-mode` needs a GUI frame, e.g. GTK or Lucid.  Terminal won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me you're using a very old version of Emacs, such as the crappy one that comes bundled with macosx.

Do yourself a favor and install something like http://emacsformacosx.com/ (and make sure you use this one rather than the other one, since you'll still have the old one installed).

`M-: emacs-version RET` will tell you which version you're using.

Comment: No--I uninstalled that version. I have emacs 24.5.1 on my system.

Comment: 24.5 would not tell you "no match" when you do `M-x doc-view-mode`.