# Viewing PDFs in Emacs

Tags: macos, pdf, emacs, terminal, latex

This is an updated post to my previous one, found here:

[Viewing LaTeX Output in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815426/viewing-latex-output-in-emacs)

I found out how to view the result of my LaTeX code in Emacs, but it gives it to me in an ugly format:

[image]

How can I ensure that the pdf viewer shows something similar to a normal pdf, such as this:

[image]

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. I have installed and linked ghostscript, but that doesn't work. Skim also doesn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As before, please note that I am running Emacs on the Mavericks terminal.

Comment: `doc-view-mode` needs a GUI frame, e.g. GTK or Lucid. Terminal won't work.

Comment: If you've "tried everything", there's obviously no point in asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jpkotta's comment is the immediate answer -- you can't expect graphical PDF rendering in a terminal.

However even in a GUI frame, you can do (much) better than the default behaviour with some additional software, so you should definitely take a look at this as well:

https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are trying is quite possible - in fact, I do it daily. I'm not running Maverick, but am running El Capitan.

To achieve what you want, you need to run emacs in GUI mode, not in a terminal. This is probably the basic problem. If you don't want to run in GUI mode, then your only choice would be to define a function in emacs which will launch the OSX preview app to display your output - this is also quite easy to do given that AucTex supports this.

Unless you provide feedback to the contrary, I'll assume you are running emacs in the terminal because that is what you get if you just execute 'emacs' at the terminal prompt. To get the GUI emacs, you need to have a version of emacs built with the necessary GUI libs installed.

As the version of emacs which comes with OSX is old, I'm also going to assume you have installed a recent version. I personally like to use homebrew for this. i.e.

```
brew install emacs --cocoa
```

Once that is done, you should be able to start emacs with

```
open Emacs.app
```

from the terminal. If that works, you should have a GUI version of emacs, running it it's own window. If you do, open up a dired buffer and navigate to where you have a pdf generated from your latex. Move the cursor to the pdf and hit enter, you *should* see a brief window with some info about doc-view rendering of the document and then see your PDF document appear in the emacs frame. This will confirm you have all the necessary libs etc to display PDF files within emacs. The next step will then be to configure Auctex to use doc-view to display pdf output. To be honest, I don't remember having to do anything to do this - it just works.

BTW, you will also notice that there is now an 'emacs' icon in the dock. You can right click on that and tell it to stay in the dock. From then on, you will be able to start emacs directly from the dock and will not need to first open a terminal and run 'open Emacs.app'. Note however, if your emacs init relies on additional environment variables to configure the startup, you will need to look iinto using launchctl to add these variables or change to setting them in your init.el